# How to use DbRef in LiteDB

Tags: c#, asp.net, litedb

How to use DbRef in [LiteDB](https://github.com/mbdavid/LiteDB). I have classes for both `Customer` and `Job`. I want the Customer to store a list of jobs that the Customer has.

So in the Customer class, I need to have a`DbRef<Job> Jobs` from what I understand. I have several issues. First, DbRef is not recognized as a type with `using LiteDB`. Second, I have no idea how to implement it

Job.cs

```
namespace HMDCompare.Classes
{
  public class Job
  {
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
  }
}
```

Customer.cs

```
using LiteDB;

namespace HMDCompare.Classes
{
    public class Customer
    {
        [BsonId]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string[] Phones { get; set; }
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }

        public DbRef<Job> Jobs { get; set; }
    }
}
```

for the DbRef I get in Visual Studio: **The type or Namespace name 'DbRef' could not be found**.

I am developing in C#/ASP.net 4.5 and with LiteDB 2.0.0-rc

Comment: A lot of things changed on the V2 version, and it seems DBRef is no more a type but a function, take a look at this example: https://github.com/mbdavid/LiteDB/blob/7aba1cd5417d3332eccfe365d061701195744fa2/LiteDB.Tests/Mapping/IncludeTest.cs

Comment: @Gusman good find. I will go over it and see how it works. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm very late, I know. But for anyone who stumbles across this: you should use the `BsonRef` Attribute. The model class would then look like this:

```cs
using LiteDB;

namespace HMDCompare.Classes
{
    public class Customer
    {
        [BsonId]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string[] Phones { get; set; }
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
        [BsonRef("collectionName")]
        public Job[] Jobs { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Instead of `collectionName` you can use the name of the collection where the data is stored, or you can leave it out.

Answer (score -1):

Using [LiteDB.2.0.0-rc](https://www.nuget.org/packages/LiteDB/2.0.0-rc) and following the example in [test page](https://github.com/mbdavid/LiteDB/issues/178), worked fine for me.

```
public IncludeDatabase() : base("mydb.db")
{
}

public LiteCollection<Folder> Folders { get { return this.GetCollection<Folder>("Folders"); } }
public LiteCollection<SubFolders> SubFolders { get { return this.GetCollection<Media>("SubFolders"); } }

protected override void OnModelCreating(BsonMapper mapper)
{
    mapper.Entity<SubFolder>()
        .DbRef(x => x.Folder, "Folders");
}
```

.....

add

```
var subFolder = new SubFolder()
{
    Name = file.Name,
    Folder = new Folder { Id = idFolder },
};

using (var db = new IncludeDatabase())
{                
    db.SubFolders.Insert(subFolder);
}
```

get

```
using (var db = new IncludeDatabase())
{                
    return db.SubFolders
        .Include(x => x.Folder)
        .FindAll().ToList();
}
```